# Добавить аргументы в метод onBindViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Как добавить ещё несколько аргументов в метод `onBindViewHolder()`? Каждый раз при попытке добавить новый аргумент, мне предлагается повторно implement'ировать опять этот метод но с дефолтными параметрами.

Comment: Никак не добавить.

Comment: @post_zeew как так то?) а как я могу линии для элемента сверху и снизу запилить тогда в recyclerView?

Comment: @Inkognito, вам нужно ItemDecorator использовать для разделителей.

Comment: onBindViewHolder() переопределяемый метод родительского класса, вы не можете изменить его сигнатуру. Для того, чтобы решить действительную проблему, пишите собственно о проблеме ("как  линии для элемента сверху и снизу запилить "), а не о ваших [неверных] представлениях о возможном решении проблемы

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Благодарю, вопрос тогда можно закрывать.

Comment: Не закрывать а снабдить ответом, ибо тут не разовая помощь именно вам а всем, кто захочет сделать так жк

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как добавить ещё несколько аргументов в метод `onBindViewHolder()`?

Никак. Адаптер для `RecyclerView` наследуется от абстрактного класса `RecyclerView.Adapter`, в котором определен список методов, которые Вы должны реализовать. Перегрузка данного метода в Вашем адаптере бессмысленна – перегруженный метод вызываться не будет, так как `RecyclerView` о существовании и назначении этого метода ничего не знает.